# Regex search across two tables

Tags: r, regex, string, performance

I have the following df with a name column and class column:

```
df=data.frame(name=c("name1","name2","name3","name4"), class=c("classA","classA","classB","classC"))
```

and I have the following dataframe where it contains a combinations of names:

```
df2=data.frame(names=c("name1;name3","name5,name6","name2 name 8","name4"))
```

I need to determine the classification of the names in df2 by performing a regex search, and labeling which class they belong to (classes) and also create a flag (class_flag):

```
df2=data.frame(names=c("name1;name3","name5,name6","name2 name 8","name4"),class_flag=c("Y","N","Y","Y"),classes=c("classA,classB", NA, "classA","classC"))
```

I have a cumbersome process to do this now which I will show but I was thinking there is a better way to do it, and I would have to do it for every class, I'm just showing it for one of the classes below:

```
class_A_search=paste(paste0("\\b",toupper(df$name),collapse = "|"))

df2%>%mutate(class_flag=ifelse(str_detect(toupper(names),class_A_search),"Y","N"), class_A=ifelse(str_detect(toupper(names),class_A_search),"classA",NA))
```

This is a simplified version of the dataset, and df2 has 1 million rows and the names column isn't limited to the ones shown here.

Comment: Rather than using regex here, it would be better to first split into individual rows, clean up the text so the format is consistent, and then use a join. You can split into rows like this `library(tidyverse); df2 %>% separate_rows(names,sep = ';|,|\\s(?=name)')`

Comment: we don't know the exact patterns

Comment: Sounds like you need to split the df1.frame names and class with comma into  separate associative arrays. Then split df1.frame names the same way. Loop the df2 names array and check df1 arrays recursively. Make comparisons with the df1 array via index. Construct df2 class_flag and classes appropriately. Believe it or not this can be done using a single pass, constructed regex.

Answer (score 2):

Probably a base R option with `regmatches` could help

```
transform(
    transform(
        df2,
        classes = sapply(
            regmatches(names, gregexpr(paste0(df$name, collapse = "|"), names)),
            \(x) {
                with(
                    df,
                    replace(
                        d <- paste0(unique(class[match(x, name)]), collapse = ","),
                        !nzchar(d),
                        NA
                    )
                )
            }
        )
    ),
    class_flag = c("Y", "N")[1 + is.na(classes)]
)
```

which gives

```
         names       classes class_flag
1  name1;name3 classA,classB          Y
2  name5,name6          <NA>          N
3 name2 name 8        classA          Y
4        name4        classC          Y
```

---

Using `dplyr`, we can try

```
df2 %>%
    mutate(name = regmatches(names, gregexpr("name\\d", names))) %>%
    unnest(name) %>%
    left_join(df) %>%
    summarise(
        classes = str_c(unique(class), collapse = ";"),
        class_flag = c("Y", "N")[1 + (sum(is.na(class)) == n())],
        .by = names
    )
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 4 × 3
  names        classes       class_flag
  <chr>        <chr>         <chr>
1 name1;name3  classA;classB Y
2 name5,name6  NA            N
3 name2 name 8 classA        Y
4 name4        classC        Y
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `tidyverse` option:

```
library(tidyverse)

lookup <- deframe(df)
df2 |>
  mutate(class = str_extract_all(names, str_c("\\b", df$name, "\\b", collapse = "|")),
         class = map(class, ~ set_names(unname(lookup[.x]))),
         class_flag = ifelse(lengths(class), "Y", "N"),
         unnest_class = class) |>
  unnest_wider(unnest_class)
```

**How it works**

1. `str_extract_all` returns a list-column with each list element corresponding to a row in the data frame. Each list element is a vector of extracted regular expression matches.
2. Since `class` is a list-column we use `map` to iterate over it and look up the extracted value in the named vector created by `deframe(df)`. `set_names` is used to create a named vector in each list element for un-nesting wider in step #4 (these become the column names).
3. `class` is still a list-column. I left it that way because there is a lot of functionality in R in dealing with lists rather than collapsing it to a string.
4. Create `class_flag` by using `lengths`, which returns 0 (equivalent of `FALSE`) if the list element is empty (e.g., `character(0)`).
5. Make a copy of the list-column `class` named `unnest_class`, which we unnest into columns.

If you really need `class` as a character column, you can pipe this output to `mutate(class = map_chr(class, str_flatten_comma))`.

**Output**

```
  names        class     class_flag classA classB classC
  <chr>        <list>    <chr>      <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
1 name1;name3  <chr [2]> Y          classA classB NA    
2 name5,name6  <chr [0]> N          NA     NA     NA    
3 name2 name 8 <chr [1]> Y          classA NA     NA    
4 name4        <chr [1]> Y          NA     NA     classC
```

---

**Benchmark**

Increasing the number of rows in `df2` to 100,000 to get a better sense of performance.

If you do not need the columns `classA`, `classB`, etc. and remove the `unnest_wider` pipe, this answer is more comparable to the one posted by @ThomasIsCoding. In the case without `unnest_wider` I found this answer to be faster, but I kept it in the benchmark because it looks like you want those columns:

```
set.seed(1)
df2 <- df2[sample(1:nrow(df2), 1E5, replace = T),, drop = F]


(bench <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  stringr = {lookup <- deframe(df)
  df2 |>
    mutate(class = str_extract_all(names, str_c("\\b", df$name, "\\b", collapse = "|")),
           class = map(class, ~ set_names(unname(lookup[.x]))),
           class_flag = ifelse(lengths(class), "Y", "N"),
           unnest_class = class) |>
    unnest_wider(unnest_class)},
  baseR = {transform(
    transform(
      df2,
      classes = sapply(
        regmatches(names, gregexpr(paste0(df$name, collapse = "|"), names)),
        \(x) {
          with(
            df,
            replace(
              d <- paste0(unique(class[match(x, name)]), collapse = ","),
              !nzchar(d),
              NA
            )
          )
        }
      )
    ),
    class_flag = c("Y", "N")[1 + is.na(classes)]
  )},
  times = 20L,
  unit = "seconds"
))

Unit: seconds
    expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
 stringr 3.759750 4.249305 4.461382 4.527822 4.732876 4.953810    20  a 
   baseR 2.736081 2.835327 3.019493 3.044236 3.137328 3.427364    20   b

ggplot2::autoplot(bench)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Other ways include:

```r
library(tidyverse)

pat <- str_c(df$name, collapse = "|")

df2 %>%
  mutate(classes = map_chr(str_extract_all(names, pat), toString) %>%
           str_replace_all(names, deframe(df))%>%
           na_if(""),
          class_flag = c("Y", "N")[1+is.na(classes)])
#>          names      classes class_flag
#> 1  name1;name3 name1, name3          Y
#> 2  name5,name6         <NA>          N
#> 3 name2 name 8        name2          Y
#> 4        name4       classC          Y


df2 %>%
  mutate(classes =na_if(str_remove_all(names, sprintf("\\b((?!%s)\\W?)+", pat)), ''),
         class_flag = c("Y", "N")[1+is.na(classes)])
#>          names     classes class_flag
#> 1  name1;name3 name1;name3          Y
#> 2  name5,name6        <NA>          N
#> 3 name2 name 8       name2          Y
#> 4        name4       name4          Y
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>